# Why isn't the divide() function working in Java BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm attempting to divide the variable 'c' by 2(stored in 'd'). For some reason that doesn't happen. I'm passing 10 and 2 for input right now.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger(sc.next()); 
    BigInteger b = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger("2"); 
    System.out.println(d);

    BigInteger c = a.subtract(b); 
    c.divide(d);
    System.out.println(c);
    a.subtract(c); 

    System.out.println(a); 
    System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting that `BigInteger` is immutable. That means that `a.divide(b)` **does not change `a`** it **returns** the **result of the calculation**.

You need `a = a.divide(b)` or similar.

```
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger(sc.next());
    BigInteger b = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger("2");
    System.out.println(d);

    BigInteger c = a.subtract(b);
    // HERE!
    c = c.divide(d);
    System.out.println(c);
    // HERE!
    a = a.subtract(c);

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

`BigInteger` is immutable. You get the result of `c.divide(d);` as the return value, which you throw away in your code.